# Python time series linear interpolation

Tags: python, interpolation

I try to interpolate irregular data to monthly resolution. the error is like this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDLJe.png)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traces/timeseries.py", line 122, in _get_linear_interpolate
    return self.default
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traces/timeseries.py", line 106, in default
    raise KeyError(msg)
KeyError: "can't get value without a measurement (or a default)"
the code is like this:

```
import datetime 

from datetime import timedelta

import traces

import re

import os

ls = []

def cal_time_series(_ff):

    with open(_ff) as _fi:

        for _l in _fi.read().splitlines():

            _vv = _l.split(',')

            if _vv[0] == 'date':

                continue

                _date = _vv[0].split('-')
                ls.append((datetime.datetime(int(_date[0]),int(_date[1]),int(_date[2])),int(_vv[1])))

ts = traces.TimeSeries(ls)

ts.sample(sampling_period=datetime.timedelta(days=30),start=datetime.datetime(2000,1,15),end=datetime.datetime(2015,12,15),interpolate='linear',)


cal_time_series('/mnt/d/thesis/code/point1.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an indentation problem with your code:

```
if _vv[0] == 'date':
    continue

    _date = _vv[0].split('-')
    ls.append((datetime.datetime(int(_date[0]),int(_date[1]),int(_date[2])),int(_vv[1])))
```

The bottom two lines will never get hit, because the iteration continues immediately prior.